# Convert an array of command line arguments and store them in an int array

Tags: c, arrays, heap-memory

I am writing a program that takes an argument array from the command line(ex. 10 20 30 40), converts them into integers and saves them in an int array to be used later. I have declared a pointer for the heap. I want to store the number count from the CL in the length variable. Then allocate space for the length and copy it to the heap. Next, use a function that converts the command line arguments to an integer and copy them in a int array.I am confused as to how I can pass the command line values. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convert(char** source, int length);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int length = 0;
  char *p_heap;

  if( argc > 11 || argc < 2 ) {
    printf("arguments 1-10 are accepted %d provided\n", argc-1);
    printf("Program Name Is: %s",argv[0]); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  length = argc-1;
  p_heap = malloc(sizeof(length));
  strcpy(p_heap, length);
  convert(p_heap, length);

  //printf("Average %f\n", avg());

  puts(p_heap);
  free(p_heap);

  return 0;
}

void convert(char** source, int length){

  int *dst;
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
    dst = atoi([i]); 
  } 


}
```

Comment: `convert` doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Comment: The [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function is passed the size in *bytes*. Furthermore, strings need to be *null-terminated* which you must allocate space fore. Then `length` is not a string, you can't copy it like a string. The compiler should be shouting quite a lot at you for the code you show.

Comment: All in all, it looks more like you have written your code by pure guess-work, without really bothering to figure out if what you think is correct actually is correct. Perhaps you should take a few steps back, buy a couple of beginners books, and start over from the very beginning. LEarning a programming language is very much the same as learning a spoken or written language, and you can't really skip the introduction and jump straight into the intermediate parts.

Comment: Surely the compiler tells you that `strcpy(p_heap, length);` is wrong, because `length` is just an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am assuming correct input from CL.

> I want to store the number count from the CL in the length variable.

If you assume correct input from CL, then you have this number in `argc-1`.

> Then allocate space for the length and copy it to the heap.

```
dst = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof *dst);
```

> Next, use a function that converts the command line arguments to an integer and copy them in a int array.

```
for(int i=0; i<argc-1; i++) 
    sscanf(source[i], "%d", &dst[i]);
```

You should also change the return type of `convert` to `int *` and then return `dst`.

Comment: upvote, at least to thank you about the usage of _sizeof_ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 1)
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    long *data = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof *data);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        char *endptr;

        errno = 0;
        data[i-1] = strtol(argv[i], &endptr, 10);

        if (*endptr != '\0') {
            fputs("Input error :(", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (errno == ERANGE) {
            fputs("Parameter out of range :(\n\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i)
        printf("%ld\n", data[i]);

    free(data);
}
```

Comment: I am not the DV, but at least a typo : `argc * sizeof *data` rather than `(argc-1) *sizeof(long)`

Comment: @bruno That's not a typo.

Comment: Not the DV, but if I should guess why, I'd pick that it's a code only answer.

Comment: oh yes, I always use `sizeof(X)` but () are useless, my bad, sorry

Comment: @bruno They may be necessary. You need them if you specify a type rather than an identifier. `sizeof int` is not valid, but `sizeof (int)` is.

Comment: anyway `(argc-1) * sizeof *data` is enough, all was not wrong in my remark ^^

Comment: I am not a downvoter, better I can be an upvoter, to thank both of you

Answer (score 0):

why the comparison with 11 in `if( argc > 11 || argc < 2 ) {` ?

in

> ```
> length = argc-1;
> p_heap = malloc(sizeof(length));
> ```

`sizeof(length)` is `sizeof(int)` and does not depend on the value of `length` if it was your hope

In

> strcpy(p_heap, length);

*strcpy* get two `char*`, *length* values the number of args rather than the address of an array of char, so the result is undefined and probably dramatic

In

> ```
> convert(p_heap, length);
> ```

the first argument of *convert* must be a `char**` but `p_heap` is a `char*`

in

> ```
> void convert(char** source, int length){
>   int *dst;
>   int i;
>
>   for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
>     dst = atoi([i]); 
>   }
> ```
>
> }

you do not use *source*

*dst* is a `int*` while *atoi* return an *int*

`[i]` ???

Before to give code on S.O. I encourage you to check first it compile without warning/error, using high warning level (e.g. `gcc -pedantic -Wextra` for *gcc* )